# Remove non-alphanumeric symbols from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string and I want to remove all non-alphanumeric symbols from and then put into a vector.

So this:

```
"This is a string.  In addition, this is a string!"
```

would become:

```
>stringVector1

"This","is","a","string","In","addition","this","is","a","string"
```

I've looked at `grep()` but can't find an example that matches.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

here is an example:

```
> str <- "This is a string. In addition, this is a string!"
> str
[1] "This is a string. In addition, this is a string!"
> strsplit(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", str), " +")[[1]]
 [1] "This"     "is"       "a"        "string"   "In"       "addition" "this"     "is"       "a"       
[10] "string"
```

Comment: I noticed there is a space in the regular expression between the ending square brackets. What is that used for?

Comment: @B.Mr.W. it preserves the spaces in the string to split upon

Comment: Thanks, finally, I am not shy to use regular expressions in R `gsub("[^[:alnum:]=\\.]", "", " Oh blah blah blah. Just be quiet!= 0.42 ")` is a lot better than cumulating several uses of the `gsub()` function to replace  each punctuation mark by `""`.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to handle this question

```
library(stringr)
text =  c("This is a string.  In addition, this is a string!")
str_split(str_squish((str_replace_all(text, regex("\\W+"), " "))), " ")
#[1] "This"     "is"       "a"        "string"   "In"       "addition" "this"     "is"       "a"        "string"
```

- `str_replace_all(text, regex("\\W+"), " ")`: find non-word character and replace `" "`
- `str_squish()`: reduces repeated whitespace inside a string
- `str_split()`: split up a string into pieces