# find and replace strings with special characters?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a bunch of titles for classroom courses that include special characters in it. I'm trying to find and replace them but it's not working

Example
Tank Walk Around â€“ Round Portable Restroom Tanks

```r
db$objectName[db$objectName == "Tank Walk Around â€“ Round Portable Restroom Tanks"] <- "Tank Walk Around - Round Portable Restroom Tanks"
```

I also have other course titles with these special characters that have been problematic as well

```
`  ’  “  „  ¢  €  ®
```

Comment: This is an encoding issue.  If possible, you'd be better off going back to the source file and ensuring that it's read into R as unicode.  Failing that you could try changing the encoding within R so that it displays correctly. `str <- "Around â€“ Round"; Encoding(str) <- "UTF-8"; str` returns `[1] "Around – Round"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep all alphanumeric characters the following code can be used. The code uses a regex expression to remove all non-alphanumerics.

```
str = "Tank Walk Around â€“ Round Portable Restroom Tanks"

print(strsplit(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", str), " +")[[1]])
```

Result:

> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')

[1] "Tank"     "Walk"     "Around"   "â"        "Round"    "Portable" "Restroom" "Tanks"

Source: [R remove non-alphanumeric symbols from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959243/r-remove-non-alphanumeric-symbols-from-a-string)